# Displaying text other than the URL in a programmatically displayed hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I'm creating a string in my code-behind, part of which contains a hyperlink. I have created my URl like so:

`var hostUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + "/thispage.aspx";`

If I include this in a string, like so:

```
`display.Text = "Your request has been recorded. To return to the 
                               home page, click here: " + hostURL;`
```

The resulting output will look something like this:

[image]

Instead, I would like to be able to create a hyperlink with a display value, so that instead of displaying the URL, I can display part of the sentence - resulting in something like this:

[image]

In raw HTML, I would accomplish this by using the display value of `a href`, like so:

`<a href="http://example.ex/thispage.aspx">--DISPLAY VALUE--</a>`

I want to achieve this, however, from my code-behind - so that I can programmatically change the text and hyperlink depending on the action that precedes displaying it. Therefore, the solution must be an attribute of `display.Text`. Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit difficult to work out what you're trying to do here. Presumably outputting a paragraph of text containing a hyperlink?
If so, I would put a Placeholder control (called phParagraph here) on the page where you want the paragraph and then you could do something like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com");
var paragraph = new Literal();
paragraph.Text = String.Format("<p>Lorem ipsum <a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a> dolor</p>", uri.AbsoluteUri, "custom text");
phParagraph.Controls.Add(paragraph);
```

Or, if you just want to drop a hyperlink on the page do this:

```
var linkButton = new LinkButton();
linkButton.PostBackUrl = uri.AbsoluteUri;
linkButton.Text = "custom text";
phParagraph.Controls.Add(linkButton);
```

Comment: j.f. is right - hyperlink - not linkbutton - is the appropriate control

Comment: You can always update your answer :). I like your first solution too though. But maybe instead of a placeholder, just use a label. Your formatted string still works. The key being the `<a></a>` tag.

Comment: Your first assumption (a paragraph) is correct. I assume that I can dump HTML into a literal like so and add it to the page where it will be interpreted as legitimate HTML, rather than creating the .ASP control in the .aspx and modifying it's `.Text` property? And also, that this is the better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do that with the hyperlink itself. It's either all or none when it comes to the "link" part of a hyperlink. In these situations, I usually resort to having a few "complimentary" labels as I like to call them. Basically just a few more labels to add some fluff.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblBeforeLink" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyp" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
<asp:Label ID="lblAfterLink" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Then in your code behind, just set the controls appropriately.

```
lblBeforeLink.Text = "Lorem ipsum";
hyp.Text = "custom text";
hyp.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com"; // your url...
lblAfterLink.Text = "dolor";
```

Resulting in something like this:

> Lorem ipsum [custom text](http://www.google.com) dolor.

Answer (score 1):

if you need dynamic URL, create `<asp:HyperLink ID="hprLink" runat="server" />` in your front page, and then use the following in code behind:

`hprLink.NavigateUrl = "http://your_web.site/";
 hprLink.Text = "Text how to display your link";`

If you need dynamic HyperLink control also, use the next in code behind:

```
HyperLink hpr = new HyperLink();
hpr.Text = "Text to be displayed as hyperlink";
hpr.NavigateUrl = "http://your_web.site/";
somePanel_or_element.Controls.Add(hpr);
```